# ASP.NET bundling and minification not working when deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I'm using the .NET 4 version of System.Web.Optimization to bundle and minificate CSS and JS files. In my development environment using Visual Studio and web development server this works great. With debug="false" the bundle files are indeed bundled as expected. When I deploy to IIS 7 using a Release build and the exact same web.config (with debug="false") the Scripts.Render still renders the list of included JS files and not the bundle file.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="GeneralScriptsAndCSS" runat="server">     
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script/common") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I have tried to access the bundle file manually in the browser and it look correct to me. The only problem is that Scripts.Render (and Styles.Render) don't seem to understand that I want the optimization enabled.

Is there a way to get log information about why the bundling is disabled? When I test further it seems as one of my pages successfully enables bundling while one does not. This is very hard to debug unless there is a way to understand why bundling is disabled for the specific page.

Edit: The bundling seems to be enabled for all pages in the root, but disabled for all pages in sub directories.

Edit 2: Looks like I solved my problem by upgrading the Nuget package to the prerelease version of 1.1.0 (beta 1).

Edit 3: Problem is back. I have deployed to other servers and bundling is enabled for all pages in the root, but disabled for all pages in sub directories. It works perfectly on some servers but only on pages in the root on some servers.

Edit 4: Found the problem. By mistake, I had additional web.config files in sub folders that overrode the debug flag (setting it to true). That's why it worken in the root folder (with debug false) and didn't work in sub folders (with debug true).